# Select2 select2-removed event is not affecting other select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm trying to reset another select2 when select2-removed event is fired but I can only affect other dom elements. I want to disable second select2 when the first select2 value is removed. This is my code, ¿Am I doing something wrong? My select2 version is 3.5. Thanks in advance.

```
 $('#element_select2_1').on("select2-removed", function (e) {
        $('#dom_element').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#another_dom_element').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $('#element_select2_2').select2('disable');
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any real documentation "select2-removed" anywhere, is that your event?  So, I created some code that will 1.  create two select2s, create a button. Register a select2 destroy event on the first selec2 and a button that destroys the selec2 triggering the event.  The triggered event disables the second select2.  Is this what you are trying to do?

```
            <script>
                $(function ($) {
                    // first select2
                    $("#sel1").select2();
                    // second select2
                    $("#sel2").select2();
                    // register event to detect select2 being destroyed
                    $("#sel1").next(".select2-container").on("remove", function () { $("#sel2").prop("disabled", true); })

                    // button that destroys the select2 triggering the event
                    $("#btn").button().click(function () {

                            $("#sel1").select2("destroy");

                    });
                })
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <select tabindex="0" id="sel1" aria-hidden="false">
                    <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
                    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
                    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
                    <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
                    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
                </select><br />
                <select id="sel2">
                    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
                    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
                    <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
                    <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
                    <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
                    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                    <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
                </select><br />
                <button id="btn" type="button">remove</button>

            </form>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming "select2-removed" is firing as expected, try

```
    $('#element_select2_2').prop('disabled', true);
```

documentation shows the property being applied to the underlying select not the select2 control.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#disabled